# View Controller в unity что эта и как эта организовывать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть проект в unity который представляет из себя главное меню игры, и мне была дана задача сделать при помощи View Controller а что эта такое и как именно организовывать в unity?

Comment: Как следует из названия - это то, что контролирует твое меню. Скрипт-костяк, методы которого привязываются к кнопкам или другим контролам меню. Считай что бекенд.

Comment: то-есть у меня вот есть несколько скриптов по разному функционалу (кнопки,скролл бары, и тд) и они повешены на разные объекты и мне их надо на какой-то один объект или скрипт повесить?

Comment: да, единый скрипт который управляет всем меню, а не что бы распихано было абы как по разных скриптах. Есть вью(твой фронтенд), а есть вьюКонтроллер(бекенд контролирующий вью)